# USB Microphone has no sound input on boot/wake, have to unplug and replug USB

Tags: windows-10, usb, audio, reboot, microphone

I have tried searching for similar issues but have not had much luck with solutions.

Whether on boot after a restart or wake after sleep, the USB microphone will not send any sound unless I unplug the cord and plug it back in. I usually replug the cord that goes into the back the mic rather than the port on the pc because I don't have to get up but have tried both and both temporarily fix the issue until the next restart/sleep.

The device is still recognized and set as the default after boot/wake, it just does not send any sound until replugging the USB.

#### What I'm using

- **Mic**: Samson Q2U attached to my desktop via USB [link](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B001R747SG)
- **Motherboard**: ASRock Z390 Taichi [link](https://www.asrock.com/MB/Intel/Z390%20Taichi/index.asp)
- **Case**: Fractal Design Meshify C [link](https://www.fractal-design.com/products/cases/meshify/meshify-c/black/)
- **OS**: Windows 10 Education 1903 (18362.592)

#### What I've tried

1. The usb ports on the back of the pc (built in to the motherboard)
2. The usb ports on the case
3. Troubleshooting the device but it finds no issues (Sound Settings > Input > Troubleshoot)
4. Disabling and enabling the microphone device in Device Manager (does nothing)

#### Possibly relevant

- While in Device Manager, I noticed an issue with one of the USB controllers. Everything else looked fine. Is this issue related or unrelated?

```
Device Type: Generic SuperSpeed USB Hub
Manufacturer: Standard USB HUBs
Location: Port_#0023.Hub_#0002
Driver Date: 3/18/2019
Driver Version: 10.0.18362.1
Status:
Windows has stopped this device because it has reported problems. (Code 43)

The USB hub failed to reset.
```

- While looking at the events on the microphone device in Device Manager under `Audio inputs and outputs` I see the following `Device not migrated` event.

```
Device SWD\MMDEVAPI\{0.0.1.00000000}.{f35af746-c71a-445b-b3d7-19cfa4fa80d1} was not migrated due to partial or ambiguous match.

Last Device Instance Id: SWD\MMDEVAPI\{0.0.0.00000000}.{0cb5b391-387d-4189-8fab-e3b3ca79a0f5}
Class Guid: {c166523c-fe0c-4a94-a586-f1a80cfbbf3e}
Location Path: 
Migration Rank: 0xF00000000000F120
Present: false
Status: 0xC0000719
```

- Also while in Device Manager in this same section, I see the microphone has an additional audio output device though this seems normal because it does have a 3.5mm output jack on it.
- Also while in Device Manager under the `Sound, video and game controllers` section I see another device for the microphone and see another `Device not migrated` event.

```
Device USB\VID_17A0&PID_0304&MI_00\7&2db0a3bb&1&0000 was not migrated due to partial or ambiguous match.

Last Device Instance Id: USB\VID_046D&PID_C52B&MI_00\7&5d89fdd&0&0000
Class Guid: {745a17a0-74d3-11d0-b6fe-00a0c90f57da}
Location Path: PCIROOT(0)#PCI(1400)#USBROOT(0)#USB(3)#USB(1)#USBMI(0)
Migration Rank: 0xF000FFFFFFFF0023
Present: false
Status: 0xC0000719
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They finally got a firmware update to fix this:

https://samsontech.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/360045374974-Q2U-Firmware-?source=search&auth_token=eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJhY2NvdW50X2lkIjo3OTcxNjAsInVzZXJfaWQiOjQwNzc4MjEzNjc3NCwidGlja2V0X2lkIjo2OTU1MiwiY2hhbm5lbF9pZCI6NjMsInR5cGUiOiJTRUFSQ0giLCJleHAiOjE1ODk0ODY3OTJ9.TTKdNsCntxSdBRt2__ccrCytYs6UIP6RYV5n5AerkBM

Comment: Just installed it, restarted, and it works! Thanks!